# Dodged boxplot in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to create a dodged boxplot without using facet_wrap as facet_wrap alters the appearance from my requirement. 
I have a dataframe with three variables - time, week_num and region

```
dput(df)
structure(list(time = c(2657L, 2319L, 2324L, 2348L, 2134L, 2251L, 
1848L, 1816L, 1893L, 2177L, 3387L, 2329L, 6964L, 2162L, 6682L, 
2268L, 5419L, 2088L, 3758L, 3021L, 2833L, 2950L, 4554L, 1213L, 
2085L, 1529L, 821L, 2406L, 2008L, 1264L, 2186L, 1654L, 1757L, 
2116L, 1876L, 2088L, 1900L, 2767L, 3051L, 1762L, 1499L, 1157L, 
1529L, 1396L, 1278L, 3367L, 1647L, 4393L, 2358L, 1535L, 2469L, 
2068L, 505L, 335L, 410L, 1159L), region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
week_num = c(20L, 22L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
21L, 19L, 19L, 22L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
22L, 22L, 18L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L)), .Names = c("time", 
"region", "week_num"), row.names = c(NA, -56L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need a dodged box plot for each region corresponding to each week_num. The code I have implemented is like this.

```
plot_df= ggplot(data=df)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=week_num,y=time,group=week_num,fill=region),position =position_dodge(width=1))
```

The plot i am obtaining is like this.

[boxplot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95EdE.png)

The fill values are not coming correctly and dodging is also not happening. For the values of x which has multiple region values, the color appears to be gray. Any way to solve the problem?

Comment: You should paste the output of the `summary(df)` call, not a picture (indent each line of said output it with 4 spaces). We also don't have your data it's unlikely aid will be forthcoming any time soon. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and modify your post as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the post with reproducible data

Comment: I will take care of it in the future questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `week_num` variable is not a factor, though you want to form your groups according to it.

The following simple line of code should achieve your desired result. (Or just change your version by adding `factor()` around `week_num`.)

```r
ggplot(df, aes(y = time, x = factor(week_num), fill = region)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Now I am able to create the plot in the required form. Thank you.